# AddEventListener dominteractive and access dom tree

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, domcontentloaded

Just wondering, taking a look at the [w3c processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#processing-model#processing-model) an event "dominteractive" exists. Its accessible through the performance api. Is it anyhow possible to bind an event on it?

[image: HTML Performance Timing Processing Model]

In my mind it should be possible to access and manipulate the dom in this early stage already since the DOM is fully loaded or?

I'm working on an app where this would help me to increase the performance quiete a lot. I don't need a fully css rendered screen which is available on domContentLoaded, however I like to quickly check for the existance of an element in the dom structure and if so load additional resources async.

As far as I tested, adding an event listener to dominteractive is not possible through addEventListener or?

```
document.addEventListener("dominteractive")
```

Are there any workarounds for it or is this just lacking browser support?

Comment: that's not an event, it's a readyState. and at the point where scripts are executing you will at least be in domInteractive state anyway

Comment: @th8472 dominteractive is not an state either. The appropriate state is "interactive". I'm not sure about readyState interactive. In case the script is syncronous it is executed before interactive state as of the docs saying the dom has closed and the writing pointer is removed on dominteractive mode change. For asyn scripts I'm not sure what happens if the page is heavy loaded, the script is lightweight and at the beginning of the page. May it be possible per specs that that in this case it may be executed even before dom interacitve is reached?

Answer (score 2):

You have to listen the event [readystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event)

```
// Log the initial readyState
console.log(document.readyState)  // loading

document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
  // The first readyStateChange will be : interactive
  // The second readyStateChange will be : complete
  console.log(document.readyState)
});
```

So this javascript code must be inline in your html file to be executed before the document is interactive.

Else you can add a safeguard like this :

```
if (document.readyState == "loading") {
  console.log(document.readyState);
  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
    console.log(document.readyState);
  });
} else {
  // document already interactive
  console.log(document.readyState);
}
```

This safeguard should be useless since you want to listen the dom interactive.